# Can someone help me add some dynamic info into my calendar

Tags: php, jquery

First of all I want to say in advance that I truly appreciate anything that anyone can contribute to my question. I have a calendar and it has the ability to show events through jquery, but how can I place info from a database into this piece of code dynamically. I know php and fairly well, but I am not sure how to add the arrays through php. This is how it will be input into the calendar with it's available options.

```
events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 1)
                },
                {
                    title: 'Long Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d-5),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d-2)
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d-3, 16, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d+4, 16, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Meeting',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Lunch',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Birthday Party',
                    start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
                    end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
                    allDay: false
                },
                {
                    title: 'Click for Google',
                    start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                    end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                    url: 'http://google.com/'
                }
```

Again, I just want to say thank you for your help. All comments, whether logical or practical are greatly appreciated.

Comment: here is a useful link. http://jhoyimperial.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/parsing-json-data-from-php-using-jquery/

Comment: Are you using FullCalendar? If so, I believe their [documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/) is sufficient for you to learn how to achieve what you want.

Comment: i think it is full calendar. A friend sent me the files, I just looked it up and it looks like exactly what I need. Thanks @Mr.J4mes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fullcalendar as mrj4mes stated

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to insert events in the calendar

```
//Start Example

var subject = $("#txtEventName").val();  //the title of the event           
var dateStart = new Date(y, m, 15);     //the day the event takes place
var dateEnd = $("#txtDateEnd").val();    //the day the event finishes


 var events = new Array();

event = new Object();
event.title = "Test first event text";
event.start = new Date(y, m, 16);    // its a date string
event.end = dateEnd;        // its a date string.
event.color = "blue";
event.allDay = false;

event1 = new Object();
event1.title = "Test second event text";
event1.start = new Date(y, m, 18);    // its a date string
event1.end = dateEnd;        // its a date string.
event1.color = "red";
event1.allDay = false;       


events.push(event);
events.push(event1);

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', events);
```